# Replaced file name with the right number

Tags: macos, renaming

I am trying to check a batch of file names and change the name the files look like the following

```
er-1.gif
```

I need to check the numbers after the dash and then look through an array to find what number i need to replace er with.

How can i create a batch file to-do this?

I have Windows & Mac available to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the filename using regex. This will return you the integer you're interested in.

Then look up the corresponding name in your array and write to a new file with the new name

If you know that the number after the '-' is the only number in the whole string you can simply use "\d" as your regex expression.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Can you help me and show me the right path to looking up the corresponding name in a array and replacing the name i just done the regex first part you said. Thanks

Comment: If it's possible don't use an array. I would prefer a HashMap (java) or Dictionary (c#) for this task. You'll have a KeyValuePair containing the number of your files as the key and the new filename as value. In Java just call: map.get("number"); and in c#: map["number"]; where "number" is the string containing the number from the filename you parsed

Comment: If you really have to use an array and you know the maximal size of the number parsed from the filename you can use this number as the index of your array

Comment: I dont need to use an array it just i didnt know how to go about it,

Comment: In that case have a look at the documentations. [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)